# Create a time object?

Tags: python

I have a vast number of files that need to be deleted past a certain date.
I can't use the datestamp of the file because the files are created some time before they are used. A file called OCT21.txt needs to be deleted a few days after October 21st, but it could have been created in May.

My question is: is it possible to convert the "OCT21" string into a format that the time module can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is in the datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html)

```
classmethod datetime.strptime(date_string, format)

    Return a datetime corresponding to date_string, parsed according to format. 
    This is equivalent to datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6])).
    ValueError is raised if the date_string and format can’t be parsed by time.strptime() or if it returns a value which isn’t a time tuple.
    For a complete list of formatting directives, see strftime() and strptime() Behavior.
```

You can give it a format (`%b%d` in your case) and it'll return the datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
target = datetime.now().strftime('%b%d').upper()
if filename == target + '.txt':
    # Do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, have a look at [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime).

```py
import time
filedate = time.strptime("OCT21", "%b%d")
```

Of course, in the resulting [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) neither the year nor exact time are valid.